# Embed Draw.io drawing in a Google Doc

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, app.diagrams.net

Is there any way to do this, apart from exporting to png or some other format and then importing into Google Doc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now.
Inside any document click *Add-ons → Get add-ons...* and search for `draw.io`.

Afterwards you will be able to add drawings through *Add-ons → Draw.io Diagrams*